# Why am I getting an uninitialized constant Api::SessionsController: error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I keep getting this error message:

```
NameError - uninitialized constant Api::SessionsController:
```

But I've double checked and my routes configuration looks correct:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do 
    resources :users, only: :create
    resource :session, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end 

  root 'static_pages#root'
end
```

My controller is also using the singular `session`:

```
class Api::SessionController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.find_by_credentials(
      params[:user][:username],
      params[:user][:password]
    )
    if @user 
      log_in(@user)
      render 'api/users/show'
    else 
      render json: ['Your request failed. Please try again.'], status: 401
    end
  end
```

And my folder structure is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Your file name and class declaration are in a singular form (`SessionsController`).

Comment: Do I need to make the file name and class declaration plural form?? From past projects I was told to use a singular resource for the session (in the routes.rb file), but is that wrong?

Comment: Whatever you feel more comfortable with (or your colleagues), just you need to make sure you're using the same name to refer to it along the whole project.

Comment: Ah ok; so the resource can either be `resource` or `resources`. But the controller and the class definition in the controller need to be plural?

Comment: Also I would recommend nesting the class for constant look up purposes e.g. `module Api; class SessionsController < ApplicationController;end;end` this way inside `Api` you can refer to it as `SessionsController` instead of `Api::SessionsController`

Comment: That's a different question. `resource` and `resources` are two different Rails methods, what needs to be always referenced in the same way is the class defined in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails have very good official guide.

Session is a [singular resource](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) without referencing an ID.

> Because you might want to use the same controller for a singular route (`/account`) and a plural route (`/accounts/45`), singular resources map to plural controllers. So that, for example, `resource :photo` and `resources :photos` creates both singular and plural routes that map to the same controller (`PhotosController`).

So you need to rename your controller to `Api::SessionsController`.

Comment: Thanks for the resource link and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

if wanna keep as you have set it up.

```
post 'session' => 'session#create', as: :session_create
destroy 'session' => 'session#destroy', as: :session_destroy
```